# How to share nodes among related users

Tags: 7, users

I have two content types called School and College.

Any user can create a new School Node or College Node. 
Suppose there are 4 users in a website. User A, User B, User C and User D. In these website User B and User C are Friends via User Relationship Module in Drupal 7.

User A create a node of School Content Type called School X.

Now User B will view School X and there should be a link called "Share Content" which will allow the User B to share School X with their friends(User C in this case, not User D).

Please let me know how to achieve this. I tried "Share content" in User Relationship Module but that feature only able to share content when user will create or edit the nodes which is not my use case.

Comment: I will prefer you to use Organic groups.

Comment: Did you find a solution?